# How to make custom RestTemplate to instrument with standard Spring Boots' Prometheus RestTemplate metrics when using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, resttemplate, spring-boot-actuator

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics), the standard http client metrics are grabbed if the `RestTemplate` is created using `RestTemplateBuilder` and then injected. However, we have a custom RestTemplate bean initialization that uses no RestTeplateBuilder, but instead `RestTemplate` is initiated with new and the `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` is passed as the parameter.

```
@Bean(name = "RestTemplateWithoutTimeOut")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateWithoutTimeOut() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        int timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(simpleClientHttpRequestFactory);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        interceptors.add(new LoggingInterceptor());
        interceptors.add(new SecureInterceptor());
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

How can we inject metrics collector (the same metrics as are collected by default) for that kind of `RestTemplate` initialization?

Comment: Why not use `RestTemplateBuilder#requestFactory`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have missed, that this method exists, thatnk a lot!

Comment: but even with this approach I need to set the `simpleClientHttpRequestFactory` to the `RestTemplateBuilder#requestFactory`, and then obtain `RestTemplate` with `RestTemplateBuilder#build`, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- could you please post this as the official answer? That really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RestTemplateBuilder` exposes methods for customizing essentially every knob that's available on `RestTemplate`. You can just call `requestFactory` and pass your customized factory, then build a `RestTemplate` instance that has all of the usual instrumentation.